# Export from XML to MySQL key and value

Tags: mysql, xml

Hello I'm trying to import data of some sommets from http://overpass-turbo.eu/ in XML format to my DB.

The XML output is:

```
<node id="45160922" lat="42.6454747" lon="1.5187225">
    <tag k="ele" v="2682"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Pic des Fangasses"/>
    <tag k="natural" v="peak"/>
  </node>
  <node id="45160950" lat="42.5902481" lon="1.4341757">
    <tag k="ele" v="2860"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Agulla de Baiau"/>
    <tag k="natural" v="peak"/>
  </node>
  <node id="45160958" lat="42.6037200" lon="1.4419886">
    <tag k="ele" v="2914"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Pic de Medecourbe"/>
    <tag k="name:ca" v="Pic de Medacorba"/>
    <tag k="natural" v="peak"/>
  </node>
```

I tried with the following code but it only imports *lat* and *lon* values:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'sommets_and.xml'
into table sommets_and_copy1
rows identified by '<node>'
```

Any help to import on the same row the *ele* and *name* values?
I'm searching something like:

```
|    id    |       name      |     lat    |    lon    |    ele  |

|  00001   |Pic des Fangasses| 42.6454747 | 1.5187225 |   2682  |
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved my problem, if it's useful for anyone:

1) Export data in .json (http://overpass-turbo.eu)

2) Data from .json to .csv

3) Import .csv into my tables